# Limit The Result / Load More [PHP Help]

Tags: php, load, limit

this script will show all user's buddies, but i want to limited it to show only 10 buddies, and when click "Show more" or "load more" then will be load all buddies. so first "i want to limited number of buddies to 10 buddies" second "i want to show all buddies with Show More (aka Load More) button/text. i searched many times but can't do it myself. can someone help me?

i think we need php for limiting buddies and ajax or jquery for show all buddies, isn't it?

**Script on template:**

```
       if (!empty($modSettings['bc_enable']) && ($context['can_bc_view']))
    {  
       global $memberContext;
       foreach($context['member']['buddies'] as $buddy)
    {
       $buddy = $memberContext[$buddy];
       echo '
    <a title="', $buddy['name'], '" href="', $scripturl, '?action=profile;u=', $buddy['id'], '">
    <div id="basicavatar" class="buddy_avatar">', $buddy['avatar']['image'], '</div></a>';
    }
```

**Source:**

```
       foreach($context['member']['buddies'] as $buddy)
    {
       loadMemberData($buddy,false, 'profile');
       loadMemberContext($buddy);
    }
       $context['can_bc_view'] = allowedTo('bc_view_any') && !$context['user']['is_owner'] || (allowedTo('bc_view_own') && $context['user']['is_owner']);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does that `echo'` do there? At least it causes a syntax error, and also breaks the code coloring.

Comment: @Pietu1998 , oh ,i just removed some extra code, it was left behind.

Comment: @imsiso Yes, but I just wanted to confirm if it had a function there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may help you.

```
$i=0;
foreach($context['member']['buddies'] as $buddy)
{
   if($i>=10){
    break;
    }else{
    $i++;
   }

   loadMemberData($buddy,false, 'profile');
   loadMemberContext($buddy);
}
   $context['can_bc_view'] = allowedTo('bc_view_any') && !$context['user']['is_owner'] || (allowedTo('bc_view_own') && $context['user']['is_owner']);
```

Comment: much appreciated!
it didn't work on source code, but i tried on template code, it works perfectly. any idea for load more?

Thanks

Comment: your welcome.one of the most important thing in this forum is supporting.I support you with my answer and you support me with your voting on my answer or by accepting them.

Comment: Sure, i did.
yes i am. i noticed once when i saw your avatar :)

Comment: Should i ask my second question again? with using "Answer Your Question" in bottom of this page? or no need?

Comment: I asked 2 questions, you solved first, now i talking about second question. "load more/show more" please read my Question Post agian. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try LIMIT keyword in mysql...like:

```
<?php
$sql='';
if(isset($_GET['limit'])==false)
{
  $sql="select * from buddies LIMIT 10";
}else
{
  $sql="select * from buddies";
}
$sql=@mysql_query($sql);
while($row=@mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
   echo($row['name']);
}
?>
<a href="your_current_page.php?limit=10">Show More</a>
```

Comment: sorry, i missed one bracket in IF statement..Now i've edited it..please try now...it will work!